# For loop while copy and pasting specific columns

Tags: vba, loops

I need a loop that will match and select different columns (not in sequential order) and paste them to another sheet all whilst keeping the condition in check. It would also be ideal if when the values get pasted that the formatting for the cell is not carried over, just the value.

Below is the code I am currently using:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("P3").Select
    For i = 3 To lr
        If Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 16), Cells(i, 26)).Copy 
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The problem is declaring the columns I want the loop to paste. I need the loop to run through the 16th column, check empty values, and then paste the index/matched value in the rows of columns 7,16,and 26 (so not in sequential order).. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: The checkmarks on the right mean these values should be copied and pasted in columns A B C on the the other sheet. The X means since there were no values in in that row for the P column, the system must skip over copying these]

Comment: Do you mean to loop in a range defined as: first column - 16th column up to the last used row? And for each cell not being empty to paste those specific cells from columns 7, 16, 26 in another sheet? If not, what " I need the loop to run through the 16th column" means?  The paste operation to be done in columns A, B, C, or in corespondent columns from where they have been collected (7, 16, 26)?

Comment: @FaneDuru I understand your confusion. The loop needs to run through the P column (#16) and check if there are any blank cells. For every cell that isn't blank, I need the code to then match the non blank cell in the P column with its value in the G,P, and Z columns (based on the row) and then paste those values in a different sheet.

Comment: When you say "match the non blank cell in the P column with its value in the G,P, and Z columns", what do you mean? Will they be concatenated, added (if numbers) and pasted in one column, or copy their values in other three columns of the second sheet? If separate columns, to be A, B, C or G, P and Z? I am asking because I intend to make some code able to solve your problem, but I do not like Sisyphus work...

Comment: @FaneDuru Right, sorry about the confusion. The latter of what you said is correct: "copy their values in other three columns of the second sheet" So just to be clear if cell P2 reads: 85 and on the same row cell G2: reads 123 and Z2 reads: House.. Then the code needs to copy those three values and paste them in columns A, B, C of the other sheet. But if a value in column P is blank, the code needs to skip the copy process for that row. Not sure if that helps?

Comment: Sorry, but still not very clear... So, the code must copy those three columns value from the examined row ONLY IF ALL THE ROW does not cpntain any empty cell?

Comment: Or only any of columns G, P and Z values from that row is not empty? I did not understand anything from your initial post regarding a condition of emptiness of the row elements... It would be good to clearly describe all necessary conditions.

Comment: @FaneDuru Right, copy the row values for G,P,Z, but only if the values are non-blank in the P column. The reason I'm only having the loop scan non blank values in the P column is because the other columns in the worksheet are contingent upon the values in the P column. If cell p2 is blank, that also mean g2 and z2 will also be blank. If still confused I could try to provide an illustration.

Comment: I'm afraid a illustration would be necessary, if my next assumption is not true: Do you need to loop only through column P:P? And if for all non empty cells to return values of the respective row for columns G, P, Z in another sheet. Are there other records in that different sheet? I mean to determine the last empty row of the column A:A and consecutively add each occurrence on P cells (plus G and Z). Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205700/discussion-between-jeremie-tomkins-and-faneduru).

Comment: I adapted the code to work for all situations. It worked when I tested it, but only for specific conditions (the area numbers of range P:P was equal with not empty number of cells). Please check it and let me know if it does what needed.

Comment: @FaneDuru, please see my recent comment to you in the chat.

Comment: I saw it and I explained you (there) that `WorksheetFunction.count` counts number because your sample contained only numbers in that column. I adapted the code to deal with your date type. Explaining in the answer when a formula it is good to be used. It was written from the beginning `'How many non empty cells in P:P (for numbers):`...

Comment: I adapted the code to work with any kind of data type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next code has to do what I understood you need. Please check it and confirm this aspect. It is very fast, working only in memory...

```
Sub PastingNextPage()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, arrIn As Variant, arrOut() As Variant
  Dim lastRowIn As Long, lastRowOut As Long, nonEmpt As Long, rngP As Range, nrEl As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, P As Long

  Set sh = Sheets("DATA"): lastRowIn = sh.Range("P" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet2"): lastRowOut = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

  arrIn = sh.Range("G2:Z" & lastRowIn).Value

  nrEl = lastRowIn - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("P2:P" & lastRowIn), "") - 2
    P = 10 'column P:P number in the range starting with G:G column
    ReDim arrOut(nrEl, 3) 'redim the array to keep the collected values
    For i = 1 To lastRowIn - 1
        If arrIn(i, P) <> "" Then
            arrOut(j, 0) = arrIn(i, 1): arrOut(j, 1) = arrIn(i, P): arrOut(j, 2) = arrIn(i, 20)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(lastRowOut, "A"), sh1.Cells(lastRowOut + nrEl, "C")).Value = arrOut
End Sub
```

It does not select anything, you can run it activating any of the two involved sheets. I would recommend to be in "Sheet2" and see the result. If you want to repeat the test, its result will be added after the previous testing resulted rows...

If something unclear or not doing what you need, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.